# Git creates a merge commit although it performs a fast-forward merge

Tags: git, git-merge, fast-forward

I'm merging a hotfix branch into master. When I do a simple `git merge hotfix-2.09` the merge fast-forwards but I'm getting a `'merge branch "hotfix-2.09"'` commit  in the log. hotfixes 01 - 08 did not do this. Am I doing something wrong with this merge or did the state of my master change some how?

edit
I guess this is not really a fast forward but acting like it.

```
[webapps@Staging www]$ git merge hotfix-2.09
Auto-merging includes/processOrderFunctions.php
Merge made by recursive.
 includes/processOrderFunctions.php |   38 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++----
 processorderPL.php                 |   29 ++++++++++++++++++---------
 2 files changed, 52 insertions(+), 15 deletions(-)
```

Comment: are you referring to the reflog? does it actually say it fast-forwarded? what does `gitk` show?

Comment: I will have to look up "reflog" but I'm looking at the git log while in on the master branch. The current first commit is "Merge branch 'hotfix-2.09'" the second commit is the commit I wanted from the merge of hotfix-2.09.

Comment: The gitk shows the merge commit has no changes in it.

Comment: I fixed it by reseting master, doing the rebase from master on the hotfix and then merging the hotfix again. I'm not sure who gets the cred below, I'll wait for people to vote up on the answers.

Comment: "merge made by recursive" clearly tells it's not fast forwarding. why do you think it's acting like a fast-forward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it fast-forwarded? You wouldn't get a merge commit if it did.

By the sounds of it, you're merging multiple hot-fixes into a branch. I assume these hotfix branches were created from the same point in time (`master`) and are not cumulative? (i.e. they all branched from `master`, not `hotfix-2` from `hotfix-1` etc...).

Then the first branch merged would fast-forward, because the parent-ref of the commits would match up to `master`. When you merged your second branch, its parent-ref would be pointing to the original `HEAD` of `master` and not the new one. This means it can't be fast-forwarded, because it's not a linear path, and this would require a merge to "flatten" the trees.

Answer (score 0):

Did you `rebase` hotfix-2.09 to master before doing the merge?